# java - selenium chrome | issue with filling an input

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I have a problem with filling an input:

My method:

```
private static void fillByID(String id, String what){
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    element.sendKeys(what);
    //System.out.println(id + " filled");
}
```

What I tried:

```
fillByID("dwfrm_singleshipping_shippingAddress_addressFields_regional_zip", "34132");
```

Html Screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jND1.png)

My Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use explicit wait with ExepecteCOndition of visibilityOfElementLocated - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you do Web Interface tests with Java + Selenium, I advise you to use the [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) Open Source Framework.

This Framework manage all Ajax problem. Example of NoraUi custom code for your case:

```
WebElement element = ...
Context.waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element), time);
```